# Stop a function making divs appearing one after another once you use a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image on which different boxes of content appears one after an other on different places of the image. I'm using this code :

```
function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(600)
              .delay(4000)
              .fadeOut(600, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();`
```

But I also have a menu next to the image. The menu items are refering to one info div.

When I click on an item, I want to pause to function and make the related item on the image appears and resume the function after some time. I really struggle making this work. Thanks in advance.

```js
var divs = jQuery('span[id^="content-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {

  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(600)
    .delay(4000)
    .fadeOut(600, cycle);

  i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

```css
.info-point {
  position: absolute;
}
.point_1 {
  top: 202px;
  left: 414px;
}
.point_2 {
  top: 381px;
  left: 200px;
}
.point_3 {
  top: 420px;
  left: 466px;
}
.point_4 {
  top: 520px;
  left: 402px;
}
.point_5 {
  top: 511px;
  left: 710px;
}
#outer-circle {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
#inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0077ae;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -8px 0px 0px -8px;
  -webkit-animation-name: bluePulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/* Tooltip */

#inner-circle:hover .tooltip-item {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -0.5em, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -0.5em, 0);
}
.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 400px;
  left: 54px;
  top: -31px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: #666;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="fact_1">How you drive</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fact_2">Where you’ve been</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fact_3">Who you know</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fact_4">Where you get on the bus</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fact_5">How is your car</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="car" class="col-md-6">
  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_1">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-1" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
     <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>How you drive</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Maximum engine revs</li>
      <li>Length of time the driver used the different driving modes</li>
      <li>Number of electromotive seatbelt tightening, e.g. due to sudden braking</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats:  loss of warranty / law enforcement</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_2">
    <a id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-2" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>Where you’ve been</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>The vehicle’s last approx. 100 parking locations</li>
      <li>The latest destinations entered into the satnav system</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats: big brother</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_3">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-3" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>Who you know</h3>
     <p>Mobile phone synced contact data (name, address, phone numbers, e-mail address and even personal images) </p>
     <span>Threats: hacking</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_4">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-4" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-right"></div>
     <h3>Where you get on the bus</h3>
     <p>Where the driver changed to other means of transport such as bus or rail</p>
     <span>Threats: profiling</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_5">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-5" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-right"></div>
     <h3>How is your car</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Detailed data of the drive battery</li>
      <li>Mileage reading</li>
      <li>Quality of the charging voltage, failures</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats: expensive maintenance / unrequested offers</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - try this.  I think it does what you want.  If it works. I'll delete the previous answer.  The logic is the same.

```js
check = false;
var i, divs;

$(function() {
  cycle();
});

divs = $('span[id^="content-"]').hide();
i = 0;

function cycle() {
  if (check == false) {

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(600)
      .delay(4000)
      .fadeOut(600, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;
  }

}

$('li a').click(function() {
  if (check == true) {
    return false;
  } else {
    divs = $('span[id^="content-"]').hide();
    check = true;
    last = i;
    div = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + div + '').fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + div + '').fadeOut('slow');
      i = last;
      check = false;
      cycle();
    }, 8000);
  }
});
```

```css
.info-point {
  position: absolute;
}
.point_1 {
  top: 202px;
  left: 414px;
}
.point_2 {
  top: 381px;
  left: 200px;
}
.point_3 {
  top: 420px;
  left: 466px;
}
.point_4 {
  top: 520px;
  left: 402px;
}
.point_5 {
  top: 511px;
  left: 710px;
}
#outer-circle {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
#inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0077ae;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -8px 0px 0px -8px;
  -webkit-animation-name: bluePulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/* Tooltip */

#inner-circle:hover .tooltip-item {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -0.5em, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -0.5em, 0);
}
.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 400px;
  left: 54px;
  top: -31px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: #666;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="content-1">How you drive</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="content-2">Where you’ve been</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="content-3">Who you know</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="content-4">Where you get on the bus</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="content-5">How is your car</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="car" class="col-md-6">
  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_1">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-1" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
     <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>How you drive</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Maximum engine revs</li>
      <li>Length of time the driver used the different driving modes</li>
      <li>Number of electromotive seatbelt tightening, e.g. due to sudden braking</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats:  loss of warranty / law enforcement</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_2">
    <a id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-2" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>Where you’ve been</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>The vehicle’s last approx. 100 parking locations</li>
      <li>The latest destinations entered into the satnav system</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats: big brother</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_3">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-3" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-left"></div>
     <h3>Who you know</h3>
     <p>Mobile phone synced contact data (name, address, phone numbers, e-mail address and even personal images) </p>
     <span>Threats: hacking</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_4">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-4" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-right"></div>
     <h3>Where you get on the bus</h3>
     <p>Where the driver changed to other means of transport such as bus or rail</p>
     <span>Threats: profiling</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer-circle" class="point_5">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <span id="content-5" class="tooltip-content clearfix">
                <div class="triangle-right"></div>
     <h3>How is your car</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Detailed data of the drive battery</li>
      <li>Mileage reading</li>
      <li>Quality of the charging voltage, failures</li>
     </ul>
     <span>Threats: expensive maintenance / unrequested offers</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just noticed that if you quickly click on the links it kinda breaks the cycle. Any idea how to avoid that ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to check if the boolean has already switched before triggering the click function.  Now a second click on any link will not work until the first click function has completed.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to make the click work before waiting for the function to be completed ?

Comment: That's what it was doing previously - and, as you pointed out, sometimes it broke.